# Trigger action on Div click but not while clicking links inside that Div

Tags: jquery, click, toggleclass

I want to toggle a class of a DIV by clicking on it, but not while clicking a link inside that DIV.

I tried this but it toggle the class even when a link is clicked:

```
$("ol.compacted .tl_general:not(a)").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("re-expanded");
});
```

What could I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 for question and anwser as I had the exactly same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stop the event propagation when clicked on link inside that div.

```
$("ol.compacted .tl_general a").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ensure that the event target is the correct element.

```
$("ol.compacted .tl_general").click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.is(e.target) ) {
        $this.toggleClass("re-expanded");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I used the @ShankarSangoli method, I don't know which one would be better to use... But thanks for your answer!